# Скрытое разговорное значение слова СПЕКУЛИРОВАТЬ

Tags: значение-слов

В словарях для слова *спекулировать* указаны прямое значение и переносное:

> Умышленно использовать что-н. в своих целях (неодобр.)

Но в разговорной речи встречается ещё одно, которое будет ясно из контекста:

> Отвечая на вопрос журналистов, обладает ли он информацией, кто виноват в данном инциденте, Столтенберг заявил, что не будет **"спекулировать на эту тему"**. "Важно собрать факты о том, как это случилось", — добавил он.
>
> https://ria.ru/syria/20160921/1477555671.html

т.е. в значении *рассуждать, высказывать мнение, не опираясь на проверенную информацию*.

Является ли данное значение отдельной единицей смысла или можно за уши притянуть к приведённому переносному толкованию?

Answer (score 4):

То, что в русском языке закрепилось как "прямое" значение (*заниматься спекуляцией* - в экономическом смысле), для исходного английского глагола *to speculate* было дополнительным, терминологическим значением (в словарях рассматривается третьим пунктом). Основное же значение этого глагола в английском связано с аспектами мышления: "*размышлять, делая предположения*", "*делать выводы умозрительно*" - как правило, в контексте отсутствия достаточной фактической информации. Приведённый вами пример этому соответствует: персонаж отказался **рассуждать** на предложенную тему **впустую**, не имея достаточной информации, "гадать".

Можно говорить о том, что перевод сделан неудачно: слово, заимствованное в русский язык в другом смысле, использовали не по назначению, исказив этим смысл сказанного. Пока рано утверждать, что с распространением подобных журналистско-переводческих штампов (они время от времени встречаются именно у журналистов, берущихся переводить) за этим словом со временем закрепится новое значение. Но если в каком-нибудь авангардном словаре оно уже приводится, можно не удивляться.

Comment: Ну да, только авто же и не говорит о прямом рксском значении (скупка-продажа, если совсем примитивно), у него изначально стоит "получение выгоды",  совсем не обязательно прямой экономической.

Comment: Если понимать сказанное как "словесный аналог спекуляции" или "выгоду на словах", то будет выглядеть, что персонаж оправдывался, мол не будет он злостно (в русском _словарном_ понимании) вводить собеседника в заблуждение, в то время как на своём языке он выразился нейтрально, о чём говорит и дальнейшее его пояснение (надо бы раздобыть факты).

Comment: Alex_ander, да я как-то не очень склонен понимать ни так, ни эдак. У вас написано "то, что в русском закрепилось как прямое" - а автор говорит о "переносном", не знаю уж, каким вы его сочтете. Но тут как ни понимай, все равно недоразумение имеет место. Или вы с ним о разных вещах, или о разных терминах для одного понятия.

Comment: Да, я это "переносном" добавил было (имелось в виду, что в аналогичном экономическому недобром смысле), но уже убрал, во избежание путаницы.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет отдельной или не отдельной единицы смысла и "за уши притянуть" - это метафизикой отдает. 
Если без этих терминов, то ситуация следующая. Значение ***Умышленно использовать что-н. в своих целях (неодобр.)*** (откуда вы его позаимствовали) не до конца передаёт все тонкости. Тут не просто использует нечто, а с привлечением какой-то комбинации, схемы, махинации даже - ну чего-то такого, что предполагает извлечение доходов "из воздуха" (не обязательно криминальных).

Так вот этому, в это, уточненное, значение ваше "спекуляция на тему" вполне укладывается. Речь идет о риторике с использовании непроверенных фактов, сомнительной информации, домыслов - и чего там еще не может себе позволить Столтенберг.

Так что вполне можно считать, что это последнее значение напрямую связано связано с тем, что названо "переносным". А уж детали, что там к чему притягивать, и отдельной единицы - это уже вопрос терминологический, я их обычно избегаю. Как раз потому, что дискуссии о них, обычно спекулятивны и неблагодарны.
//=====

Слушайте, а ведь все сильно упростится, если основываться на определениях Кузнецова.

> СПЕКУЛИРОВАТЬ, -рую, -руешь; нсв.
>
> 1. Заниматься спекуляцией (1 зн.).
>      С. дефицитными товарами.
> 2. чем, на чём. Строить свои планы, расчёты
>      С. на трудностях. С. на чьей-л. доверчивости. С. именем знаменитого
>      предка. <Спекульнуть, -ну, -нёшь; св. Однокр. Разг. Решил с.
>      произведениями искусства.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB*&all=x

Здесь вообще нет вашего "переносного".  Есть два русских значения (английский выносим за скобки), первое из которых, допустим, можно назвать прямым, а второе пусть будет "переносное", но **оно точно подходит под описанную ситуацию**.

Так что здесь скорее надо ***Ваше*** "переносное" определение шерстить на предмет соответствия последнему (тому, что у Столтенберга), а не наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Ищем (например, в Большом толковом словаре Кузнецова) слово "спекуляция":

> > 2. СПЕКУЛЯЦИЯ, -и; ж. [лат. speculatio - созерцание, умозрение] Книжн. Философское умозрительное построение, не подтверждаемое фактами. Идеалистические спекуляции. <Спекулятивный, -ая, -ое. С-ая философия. С-ые рассуждения (умозрительные). Спекулятивность, -и; ж. С. построений.

Так вот, Столтенберг (вернее, его переводчик) использовал глагол "спекулировать", который происходит от слова "спекуляция" в его втором значении.

И это не "разговорная речь", а наоборот, *Книжн.*, как помечено у Кузнецова.